# Using regex is picking up on plus symbols when it shouldn't

Tags: python, regex

I have this regex here:

```
"\d+.?\d*\^\d+\.?\d*"
```

What it should be doing is finding something like `2^10` in a string like `1*1+2^10*1` but it comes back with `1+2^10`.

What am I doing wrong? I assume it is something to do with the `.`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In regular expressions, the `.` character stands for "match any character". You will have to escape it:

```
"\d+\.?\d*\^\d+\.?\d*"
```

You can try out your regular expression using [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/)

Comment: +1. It's probably worth mentioning that it's almost always a good idea to use raw string literals with regex, but in this case it shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: Raw string literals? Can you explain? Someone mentioned it in another question but I didn't really know what they were talking about

Comment: @SmartLemon: prepend your string with an r: `r"raw string"`, see the python documentation on [string literals](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

Comment: A raw string literal is a string value that does not respect (python) escapes. You would specify them by prefixing the string with an `r`, e.g. `r"My\.Pattern"`